# Загрузка изображения на сервер и получение ссылки

Tags: php

Доброе время суток:).
Делаю редактор для WordPress, сайт будет содержать изображения, из-за этого и возникла проблема: как сделать загрузку изображения на сервер и получить ссылку? Желательно переименовать файл в цифры что бы исключить возможность того что несколько пользователей загрузят файл с одинаковым именем

Comment: @sergiks, раньше не замечал этого в кодексе... Как только опробую отпишусь тут, спасибо за то что ткнули

Comment: @sergiks, да, действительно то что нужно :). Переконвертируйте коммент в ответ, отмечу как решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так сам [WP умеет разбираться](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) с загруженными файлами. Не вариант?